# Want to restart service if application stopped by user from application manager.

Tags: android, service, restart

I'm using a sticky android service by using code snippet in service class

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

But it restarts only when app get force closed by android o/s, Although when user force stop app from application manager, service also get terminated.
However, my requirement is that I want to keep running service forever till app is installed in device.
Could any one help me on this?

Comment: What does your service do? If it is constantly running, you have a design problem, as that would drain the battery. Preventing the user from killing your service make it seem to me like you are doing something you don't want the user to know / control...

Comment: Yes Nicklas, I understand the issue, but it's client requirement and it's app functionality that want to keep track of the logged in user if app is installed.

Comment: You are probably still better off with another solution than a constantly running Service. You can register for a broadcast when your app is uninstalled, and send a message to the server. Along with this, you could assume that your application is uninstalled, if the server hasn't received a message from the device in a present amount of time (in case the user had no internet connection while uninstalling). As far as "logged in" status goes, do you mean if the user is logged in to the app, or actively using the device? In either case, you will not need a Service to check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through long research and blogs recommendation, if **user** click force close application from application manger, then there is no way to restart again automatically.

Though, there can be work around to start stopped service by following broadcasts like - Usb detection, bluetooth status change, device restart etc. In these cases device send broadcast and if your app is capable to receive these notification, you can restart your service from context received in broadcast.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `Forground Service` to make your service alive.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Notification notification=new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"The Service Is Running",System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent j=new Intent(this, Activity.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            j, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Notification Message", "RunningService", pi);
    notification.flags|=Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    startForeground(1, notification);


    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: How this Forground Service will work if user select to stop application from application manager?

Comment: @Pankaj : that service would be alive until the notification is up there.it might terminated just when the device is on low available memory

Comment: Hi Arash, I just tried your code, when I run the app, a notification were shown, but once I stopped the app from application manager (force stop) notification were gone, and service terminated. Here I want to keep running. Hope you can help on it.

Comment: @Pankaj : you cant prevent it from force stop or when memory is low but it makes your service alive when your app turned away from task manager.even services like Viber or etc, can be force stopped by user.but you can make a schedule for that to turn it on again.

Comment: *Make a schedule for that to turn it on again: Means you want to say start through any other app or some other way? could you please explain it little @Arash?

Comment: @Pankaj : like scheduling an AlarmManager to restart your service

Comment: Arash, scheduling AlarmManager will be also associated to that particular app, once app will be force stopped then AlarmManager will be removed. Not it?

Comment: No, AlarmManager will work even your app is completely closed and force stopped.

Answer (score -1):

Its not possible .But you can use foreground service . in low memory case android os can kill foreground service